# how to get authorization to save image in media library: windows phone, c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

i attempt to save image in media library

```
 private bool saveImage(WriteableBitmap bmp)
        {
            using(var mediaLibrary=new MediaLibrary())
            {
                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    var fileName = string.Format("Gs{0}.jpg", Guid.NewGuid());
                    bmp.SaveJpeg(stream, bmp.PixelWidth, bmp.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
                    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    var picture = mediaLibrary.SavePicture(fileName, stream);
                    if (picture.Name.Contains(fileName)) return true;
                }
            }
          return false;
        }
```

and im getting the error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.Interop.ni.dll

Additional information: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.

help me to overcome this issue.

Comment: make sure that you add the `ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO` capability in your `WmAppManifest`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MediaLibrary.SavePicture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.savepicture.aspx) will rise an UnauthorizedAccessException if the app doesn't declare the ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO capability in its [WMAppManifest.xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff769509(v=vs.105).aspx)